# android export eclipse project from 32 bit to 64 bit system

Tags: java, android, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to take an Android Eclipse project that I am learning  in office(Win XP 32bit 32) to my home (Win 7 64 bit java) .

I am assuming I can zip up the project folders and all sub-folders from office and import in on my home eclipse and it should work . Will there be any 32 bit - 64 bit compatibility issues?

Comment: There should be no problem with that.

Comment: but one has 64 bit java and another 32 bit java ,not to mention different version of adt-eclipse bundle (32 and 64 bit respectively). SHouldn't it cause an issue?

Comment: Sure, the environment is different. But the java project **inside** eclipse is the same.

Comment: @misguided : but you aren't importing the Java VM, or the plugins, only the projects. Those should be architecture-independent. Try it and edit your question if it causes any problems.

Answer (score 0):

there is no issue for x86 or x64 win os

```
step1 File->Import->Android->Existing Android code into Workspace, Next

step2 Select root directory: browse the existing project folder in the computer

step3: Projects->Select All

click-> Finish
```